# WebView2 в .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Согласно [туториалу Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) для работы с WebView2 необходимо установить Edge Canary. У меня была следующая проблема: на рабочем компьютере был установлен Edge WebView2 Runtime 106.0.1370.42, в проект добавлен пакет Microsoft.Web.WebView2 версии 1.0.1370.28 и всё прекрасно работало (без Edge Canary). На сервер я установил Edge WebView2 Runtime 106.0.1370.**47** (другой версии на офсайте нет), запустил сборку и получил такую ошибку при инициализации CoreWebView2:

> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.WebView2RuntimeNotFoundException: Couldn't
> find a compatible Webview2 Runtime installation to host WebViews.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
> specified. (0x80070002)

Попробовал обновить Runtime на рабочем компьютере до версии 106.0.1370.47. В результате вообще работать перестало везде с этой ошибкой. Удалил Runtime, установил Edge Canary - всё прекрасно, всё работает везде. Однако я не понимаю почему я доложен устанавливать браузер (Edge Canary), а не Runtime? И хотелось бы положить просто всё необходимое для работы в папку с проектом (так понимаю это [fixed version](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section)), чтобы предварительная установка чего-либо вовсе не требовалась.

Comment: _На сервер я установил_ - сервер под Windows, я полагаю?

Comment: @aepot Windows Server 2022

Comment: _На рабочем компьютере под Windows 10 всё работает, на сервере - нет_ - В таком случае проблема на стороне винды или рантайма. Возможно он просто не совместим с Win Server. И странно, зачем браузер на сервере...

Comment: _"И странно, зачем браузер на сервере..."_ - Я использую браузер для создания скриншотов. Дело в том, что на сервере осуществляется сбор данных и к отчётам нужно прикреплять развёртку, которая векторной графикой рисуется на сайте в HTML-элементе. То есть данные загружаются в HTML-сниппет, тот в браузер и дальше скриншот. Было принято решение перейти на WebView2, так как он не жрет память и гораздо более легковесный, чем кукловод или CEF. _"Возможно он просто не совместим с Win Server."_ - Кстати, хочу напомнить, что с установленным Edge Canary всё работает на сервере.

Comment: Надо отлаживать, искать нестыковку. Универсального лекарства здесь нет. Сами в курсе, что без Canary работает на обычных машинах, значит есть шанс и на серваке это вылечить. А вообще странно, что отчет отрисовать в браузер можно, а в файл нельзя. Рисовалка отчетов кривая, не поддерживает? Почему бы ответ в HTML формате тогда не готовить? Его вроде-как даже в PDF можно отконвертировать. Скриншоты это ж костыль. Либо выгрузить числовые данные статистики и отрисовывать графики самостоятельно.

Comment: Вы не правильно меня поняли. Некоторые собираемые данные представляют собой точки, означающие некоторые области на карте. На сайте это представлено элементом, в который загружаются точки и он отображает определённый SVG. Именно изображение этого SVG и нужно добавить в отчеты.